# DRF dynamic select field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

```py
class DealSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    organization = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(style={'placeholder': 'Организация'},
                                                      label='Организация', required=True,
                                                      queryset=Organization.objects.all())
    services = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Service.objects.all(),
        many=True,
        label="Услуги",
        required=True)
```

How to make sure that the services, or rather their queryset, change in the template depending on the choice of the organization?
P.S.
Each organization has its own services. It must work without reload page.

Comment: i think it must be work with ajax...